# Array not being sorted by A-Z?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be opening files in a folder by A-Z.

format for the files is:

```
All_Employee_Data_(Active)_-_Corp
All_Employee_Data_(Active)_-_DC
Hires_Month_01
Hires_Month_02
Hires_Month_03
New_Hire_-_Termination_Trend_By_Week_and_ELT_LY_to_CY
Salary_Current_-_Corporate
```

I use this script to do a sort for the array of filenames, but it isn't sorting anything, just deleting the array.

```
Option Explicit
Dim strfiledate As String
Sub Sort_AthroughZ()

Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, arr As Object, ofile As Object
strfiledate = GetSetting("'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate")
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("J:\Analytics\Report Originals\All Data (Nest)\" & strfiledate)
Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each ofile In oFolder.Files
    arr.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
Next ofile

arr.Sort

End Sub
```

everything was working fine, and the whole array is set in `arr`, but when the code hits `arr.sort`, it deletes out the whole array list and leaves just the last file.

full code with other module:

```
Option Explicit
Dim strfiledate As String
Sub Update_Data_And_OPR()
    Dim wbTemplate As Workbook: Set wbTemplate = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsInputs As Worksheet: Set wsInputs = wbTemplate.Worksheets("Inputs")
    Call LudicrousMode(True)
    With wbTemplate
        Dim varWsName As Variant
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        ReDim varWsName(1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count - 6)
            For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                Select Case ws.Name
                    Case "Inputs", "Data --->>>", "Stores", "Hires", "Terms", "SalStores"
                    Case Else
                        i = i + 1
                        varWsName(i) = ws.Name
                End Select
            Next
    End With
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, arr As Object, ofile As Object
    strfiledate = GetSetting("'HR_METRICS_TEMPLATE_v3.xlsm'", "Update_New_Data", "FileDate")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("J:\Analytics\Report Originals\All Data (Nest)\" & strfiledate)
    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    For Each ofile In oFolder.Files
        arr.Add oFSO.GetBaseName(ofile)
    Next ofile
    
    arr.Sort
    
    Dim BasePath As String: BasePath = "J:\Analytics\Report Originals\All Data (Nest)\" & strfiledate & "\"
    Dim Filename As String: Filename = Dir(BasePath & "\*.xlsx")
    Dim wb As Workbook
        i = 0
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Select Case True
                Case InStr(Filename, "Active_Corporate_Listing_for_Payroll")
                Case InStr(Filename, "All_Employee_Data_(Active)_-_Store")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Corporate_Salary_Report")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Average_Store_Count")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Hires_Month")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Salary Current_-_Store")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Terms_Month")
                Case InStr(Filename, "YTD_Terminations_Corporate")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Field_-")
                Case InStr(Filename, "YTD_Terminations")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Store_Active_Count")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Store_LOA")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Visual_Lab_Associates")
                Case InStr(Filename, "VP_and_Above_Listing")
                Case InStr(Filename, "Store_Termination_Chart")
                Case Else
                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(BasePath & "\" & Filename, , True)
                i = i + 1
                    With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                       .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=wbTemplate.Worksheets(varWsName(i)).Cells(1, 1)
                    End With
                wb.Close
            End Select
            Filename = Dir
        Set wb = Nothing
        Loop
        Call Merge_Stores
        Call Merge_Hires
        Call Merge_Sal_Current
        Call Merge_Terms
        With ThisWorkbook
            Dim strFileName As String: strFileName = "Combined NEST Data_"
            ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "C:\Users\Desktop" & "\" & strFileName & strfiledate & ".xlsm"
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Call LudicrousMode(False)
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you do with `arr` after the sort?  Seems like this can't be your complete code...

Comment: @TimWilliams i am using it to then open up each file individually and place that into a worksheet, but that's called upon in a separate module

Comment: So how does arr get to that other module?  It goes out of scope as soon as Sort_AthroughZ() exits.

Comment: It works to: just colapse and expand, `arr` will be shown sorted... Bug in IDE, not in runtime!

Comment: @TimWilliams ok I just placed it in the other module, and also pasted my full code

Comment: After the `Sort`, you are never use `arr` again ?!?

Comment: @FunThomas where else should I be using it? After the sort, its worked just fine in the past

Comment: You are aware that this sorts strings in the array, not in the file system?

Comment: @FunThomas how would i go about sorting the file system instead? I thought it was doing that because of the scripting runtime language

Comment: You fill an array and sort it, then never use the array.  Why?

Comment: I just found that code online to sort the file system so that I can open up files alphabetically. it's been working, but yeah i realize that I never call upon that array after the sort. What should I be doing?

Comment: loop over the sorted array (`arr`), and open the file with the according name. Files in a FileSystem usually don't have an order. If you open an File Explorer in Windows and sort the files there, you are sorting a list for display reasons, but someone else can sort them in a complete different order in the same moment.